# Bash: search up a directory tree

Tags: bash, shell

I have a source code tree whose root is at something like `/home/me/workspace`.  There are many subdirectories many levels deep.  In particular there is a path containing some tools:

```
/home/me/workspace/tools/scripts
```

I am writing a bash function which I can call from any place in the tree to which I pass the string `tools/scripts`.  The function should iterate its way from the present working directory to `/` looking for path fragment `tools/scripts`, then if it finds it, print out the absolute path in which it is found.  In this example, `/home/me/workspace` would be printed.  If the path fragment is not found at all, then nothing is printed.

I already have the following bash function which does this for me:

```
search_up ()
(
    while [ $PWD != "/" ]; do
        if [ -e "$1" ]; then
            pwd
            break
        fi
        cd ..
    done
)
```

but this seems a bit long-winded.  I am wondering if there are any other ways to do this either in bash itself, or in perhaps a single `find` command, or any other common utility.  I'm particularly looking for readability and brevity.

Note I am **not** looking for a full recursive search of the entire tree.

Also my bash is not the latest, so please no tricks using the latest, greatest:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$
```

Comment: You need find relative directory path or absolute directory path? Absolute path is already known. So, you want a relative path from pwd. Is it?

Comment: I need to find the absolute directory where the `tools/scripts` path fragment exists.

Comment: Why do you need to traverse back up the tree? Why not just refer to ~/workspace/tools/scripts ?

Comment: @RobKielty - ~/workspace is not a given - it will be wherever the tree gets pulled next.

Comment: customary way to handle such thing is to set a TOPDIR variable (e.g. from a config file edited by user) and build all paths relative to it.

Comment: You may have already seen these similar questions across StackExchange: http://superuser.com/questions/455723/is-there-an-upwards-find , http://serverfault.com/questions/412451/is-there-an-upwards-find , http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/is-there-a-way-to-find-a-file-in-an-inverse-recursive-search - but it looks like the answer is no - you're already there with your function.

Comment: @wodow - thanks for pointing these out - I don't think there is much there that is a significant improvement over what I already have.  I was intrigued by the [recursive solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/is-there-a-way-to-find-a-file-in-an-inverse-recursive-search/13474#13474), but I think what this gains in brevity is lost in readability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work but tell me if it needs compatibility with POSIX. The advantage of this is that you don't need to change your directory to higher level just to make the search, and also no need to use a subshell.

```
#!/bin/bash

search_up() {
    local look=${PWD%/}

    while [[ -n $look ]]; do
        [[ -e $look/$1 ]] && {
            printf '%s\n' "$look"
            return
        }

        look=${look%/*}
    done

    [[ -e /$1 ]] && echo /
}

search_up "$1"
```

Example:

```
bash script.sh /usr/local/bin
```

Output:

```
/
```

Comment: +1 - Definitely better in general not to have an extra subshell, though I don't expect this function to be used extensively to really warrant such an optimization.

Comment: The OP's function does not change pwd. Check it out: parens instead of curlies at the top level of the function definition. Who knew? (thumbsup)
Try: `function foo () (cd /etc; pwd)` then `foo; pwd`

Comment: Need to search for closest of multiple names: https://gist.github.com/mscalora/3f9756735036c27b7b13b9063c054d1d

Comment: @Mike There's an extra `=` in `local look=${PWD%/}=`.  Also `$name` in `"$look"/$name` is better include inside the quotes.  `in "$@"` is also optional.

Answer (score 4):

For the record, here is what I ended up using:

```
while [ $PWD != "/" ]; do test -e tools/bin && { pwd; break; }; cd .. ; done
```

Similar to my OP, but in the end I was able to drop the subshell parentheses () completely, because this line is itself invoked using the "shell" command from another program.  Hence also stuffing it all onto one line.

I still liked KonsoleBox's well-reasoned answer as a possibly more general solution, so I'm accepting that.