# Search up through directory path to find a specific directory

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, terminal

I understand how to recursively search down a hierarchy for a file or directory, but can't figure out how to search up the hierarchy and find a specific directory.

Given a path & file such as these fellas :

```
/Users/username/projects/project_name/lib/sub_dir/file.rb
/Users/username/projects/project_name/lib/sub_dir/2nd_sub_dir/3rd_sub_dir/file.rb
/Users/username/projects/project_name/spec/sub_dir/file.rb
```

How using the terminal can I get :

```
/Users/username/projects/project_name
```

N.B. I know that the next directory down from `project_name` is `spec/` or `lib/`

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? Surely there is a better way - but we have to know why you're trying to do this. I have a feeling this is going to turn out to be an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).

Comment: Learnt something new with the `<!-- language: none -->` Thanks :-)

Comment: So you are looking for the common ancestor to a list of file paths?

Comment: @FredrikPihl Yep :-) I actually changed it to `<!-- language-all: none -->` so it applies to all the following code blocks.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - even better. I'll start using that one from now

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011167/bash-search-up-a-directory-tree

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it's actually part of a SublimeText 3 build system for Ruby and RSpec.

Comment: The build system sends your current .rb file in Sublime via AppleScript to the Terminal and runs it.

RSpec expects you to run it from your current project directory. If between tests you `cd` somewhere else in the Terminal and you forget to `cd` back to your working directory, then you start another build from Sublime, you can get errors.

This functionality allows the build system to automatically `cd` to the correct working directory before running the test.

[The build system on Github](https://github.com/dwkns/sublime-ruby-terminal)

New functionality not yet added to that repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure bash (no sub-processes spawning or other commands). Depending on how flexible you want it to be you may want to consider running the argument of `rootdir()` function through `readlink -fn` first. Explained [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#VARMATCH).

```
#!/bin/bash

function rootdir {
  local filename=$1
  local parent=${filename%%/lib/*}
  if [[ $filename == $parent ]]; then
    parent=${filename%%/spec/*}
  fi
  echo $parent
}

# test:
#  rootdir /Users/username/projects/project_name/lib/sub_dir/file.rb
#  rootdir /Users/username/projects/project_name/spec/sub_dir/file.rb
#  rootdir /Users/username/projects/project_name/lib/sub_dir/2nd_sub_dir/3rd_sub_dir/file.rb
# output:
#  /Users/username/projects/project_name
#  /Users/username/projects/project_name
#  /Users/username/projects/project_name
```

Comment: It works like a charm, but I'm struggling to get my head round exactly how it does what it does. Can you give me a quick rundown. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use perl:

```
cat file | perl -pe "s#(.+)(?:spec|lib).+#\1#"
```

where in file:
/Users/username/projects/project_name/lib/sub_dir/file.rb /Users/username/projects/project_name/lib/sub_dir/2nd_sub_dir/3rd_sub_dir/file.rb /Users/username/projects/project_name/spec/sub_dir/file.rb

or you can use sed:

```
cat file | sed 's/\(^.*\)\(spec\|lib\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: problem is that there is no *file* just a file-hierarchy i.e. no file to parse.